# Does a set has the same elements as a list in Java?

Tags: java, list, set

I have an `ArrayList<SomeObject>` in java which contains some `<SomeObject>` multiple times.
I also have a `Set<SomeObject>`, which contains some elements one time only. The elements are only uniquely distinguishable only by their name (`String SomeObject.Name`).

How am I possible to see if the list has exactly the same elements as the set, but maybe multiple times?

Thanks

Comment: The sets .retainAll() method will leave only the common elements. Do you want a true/false that they contain the same elements? You can brute force using .contains on the set for each array member

Comment: @RichardTingle I do not want to edit my initial set. In addition, the objects might not be actually the same. They only have the same name, which that makes them equal for my system. In addition, Set, contains everything the List has, but maybe also some more. Therefore my question is whether the # of unique items at the list is equal with the # of the size of the set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several collections libraries to do this.  For example commons-collection: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEqualCollection-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-

**eg. `CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(myList, mySet)`**

If you have to write it yourself, no libraries, then just check that each contains all the elements of the other:

```
`mySet.containsAll(myList) && myList.containsAll(mySet)`
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the ArrayList to a set by using HashSet:

```
HashSet listSet = new HashSet(arrayList);
```

To check whether the `ArrayList` initially has more elements, just compare the `listSet` and `arrayList` `size()` results:

```
boolean sameSize = listSet.size() == arrayList.size()
```

Then you can get the intersection of the two sets (the elements they have in common):

```
listSet.retainAll(set1)
```

If `listSet.size() == set1.size()` now, then they had the same elements, as all elements in the two lists were shared in common. To check whether the arrayList had repeating elements initially, check the value of the boolean from before: if `sameSize` is `true`, then they did, `false` means that they didn't.

Comment: Had a feeling there would be a nice built in function; this is why I didn't answer using my comment

Comment: I really like this solution. :) But will it be ok with my problem? as I might have two items that are not the same, but have the same value (name)...

Comment: @Jim this will use the .equals method. As long as you override that to represent your version of "equals" then you'll be fine (remember to override hashcode as well)

Comment: @JimBlum, what Richard Tingle said.

Comment: @MartinDinov Thanks a lot. But I get Sets cannot be resolved error at this line Sets.difference(set1, listSet); If I change the Sets to Set I get the error The method difference(Set<SomeObject>, HashSet) is undefined for the type Set... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, removed the previous solution as `Sets` is not standard Java but in the Guava libraries only (which I was recently using and so got confused). Hopefully the updated answer makes sense and works for you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the simplest one-line solution to this is probably

```
return new HashSet<SomeObject>(list).equals(set);
```

...which just identifies the unique elements of `list` and verifies that that matches `set` exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- add all you List elements to Set and check if the size is the same;
- create a new List based on your Set and check is they are equals.

Answer (score 0):

All Java collections have method `boolean containsAll(collection<>)`, so if we want to check if two collections contain same elements, we can write `collection1.containsAll(collection2) && collection2.containsAll(collection1)` which will return `true` if `collection1` and `collection2` contain same elements.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Hash that is a String and an Integer of the count of how many time.  Interate thought the list create a Hash entry and setting to one if element exists already add one to the count.

```
Hash<String, Integer> hash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String s : list) {
    if (hash.containsKey(s))
        hash.put(s, hash.get(s)++);
    else
        hash.put(s,1);
}
```